# Running seesaw and overtone libraries in clojure

Tags: clojure, namespaces

I want to use the overtone and seesaw namespaces in one project. However when i load them there seems to be a shared function named (select) which exists in both seesaw.core and overtone.core ((seesaw.core/select) (overtone.core/select)), why i can't load both of the namespaces in the project. How could i come up with this? Will using `refer` with the `:exclude` keyword an option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While many tutorials and examples use the `use` function or the `:use` clause in the `ns` form, in real code it is better to never do this. The preferable form is as follows:

```
(ns foo.bar
  (:require [a.something :as some]
            [b.another :as a]))

(some/f)

(a/f)
```

The functions are fully distinct and unambiguous, and also this makes the code easier to read and refactor - you have a clear indication of where the definitions you are using come from.

Comment: So is this true to say: because `use` loads also the namespace specifications of the functions (vars) it makes vars to collide with each other preventing namespaces to load **healthy**, while `require` dosn't do so? And thats why it works with require?